# Getting MySQLSyntaxErrorException?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have this code :

```
    String check="SELECT COUNT(*) as check FROM recordstudent WHERE STUDENT_ID="+T_STUDENT_ID+" AND COURSE_ID="+T_COURSE_ID+" AND PACKAGE_ID="+T_PACKAGE_ID+" AND ACTIVITY_ID="+T_ACTIVITY_ID+" AND DATE="+T_DATE+ ";";
    rs=myStmt.executeQuery(check);
    int ch=0;

    while(rs.next()){

        ch=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("check"));
    }

    if(ch==0)
    {

        String insertRecord="insert into recordstudent"+
                "(STUDENT_ID,COURSE_ID,PACKAGE_ID,ACTIVITY_ID,TEST_NAME,DATE,SCORE,TOTAL_MARKS,PERCENTAGE,CORRECT_ANSWER,TOTAL_QUESTIONS,STUDENT_NAME,SCORE_PER_DIVISION,ATTEMPTS)"+
                "VALUES("+
                "'"+T_STUDENT_ID+"',"+
                "'"+T_COURSE_ID+"',"+
                "'"+T_PACKAGE_ID+"',"+
                "'"+T_ACTIVITY_ID+"',"+
                "'"+T_TEST_NAME+"',"+
                "'"+T_DATE+"',"+
                "'"+T_SCORE+"',"+
                "'"+T_TOTAL_MARKS+"',"+
                "'"+T_PERCENTAGE+"',"+
                "'"+T_CORRECT_ANSWERS+"',"+
                "'"+T_TOTAL_QUESTIONS+"',"+
                "'"+T_STUDENT_NAME+"',"+
                "'"+T_SCORE_PER_DIVISION+"',"+
                "'"+t+"'"
                +");";

                myStmt.execute(insertRecord);



    }
```

This snippet should insert the data in database only if the ch=0 .But I am getting this error:

```
      com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
          You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
          to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
          'check FROM recordstudent WHERE STUDENT_ID=11 AND COURSE_ID=2 AND PACKAGE_ID=11 A' 
          at line 1
```

Can Anyone help me and solve my problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`check` is a reserved word. Surround it with backticks: `` `check` ``

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally: don't build your SQL this way. I notice that you've put quotes round the values in the "insert" SQL statement - but not in the "select" one. That's the start of the problem - but you shouldn't be including values like this in your SQL to start with. You should use *parameterized SQL* via `PreparedStatement`, and set values for the parameters. Benefits:

- You can see your actual SQL more easily, so you'll be able to spot syntax errors. (This is basically keeping your code separate from your data.)
- (**Very important**) You won't be open to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)
- You won't need to worry about conversion issues for numbers, dates and times etc

There are *other* problems in your SQL (such as spaces and `check` being a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL), but the *very first thing* you should fix is how you use values. Until you've done that, your code is *inviting* security problems.

(You should then start using more conventional variable names than `T_STUDENT_NAME` etc, but that's a different matter.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'check' FROM recordstudent....
```

instead of

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as check FROM recordstudent....
```

I think check is a keyword